# Semantic Web - Policy Enforcement (Hewlett Packard) - Issued Patent - Prior Art Request

Tags: prior-art-request, post-grant, semantic-web, us8498959

An overbroad patent for **"Policy Enforcement"** was granted to [Hewlett-Packard](http://hp.com) July 20, 2013.

"It heavily constrains commercial exploitation of research done in the **Semantic Web/Semantic Web Services** community from 2001-2009." - [Martin Hepp](http://www.heppnetz.de/)

[US8498959 "Policy Enforcement"](https://www.google.com/patents/US8498959)

- Prior Art Date: Seeking prior art predating **November 28, 2009**
- Patent Number: [8498959](https://www.google.com/patents/US8498959)

Why [New HP patent could be a barrier to semantic web services adoption](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/semantic-web/2013Jul/0143.html)

Comment: Spoke to USPTO innovation office folks in NYC Aug 22 and brought this to their attention. Will follow up again.

Answer (score 4):

I did some work about 2002-03 which is described in one of the deliverables for the EU-funded SWAD-E research project (http://www.w3.org/2001/sw/Europe/):

http://www.w3.org/2001/sw/Europe/reports/pdf/11.2b.pdf

See also:

http://www.ninebynine.org/SWAD-E/Scenario-HomeNetwork/HomeNetworkConfig.html

This work includes use of RDF technologies to set access controls on a Cisco IOS router, which appears to correspond to the first primary claim of the patent:

> 1. An enforcement system for enforcing policies with regard to service requests comprising a processor-readable, non-transient medium storing
>    code representing instructions that when executed at a processor cause
>    the processor to implement: a plurality of enforcer agents adapted to
>    enforce policies; at least one explorer agent adapted to evaluate
>    policy enforcement capabilities available to the enforcement system;
>    and a policy decision point adapted to identify the policies that need
>    to be enforced for a service request and to pass this information to
>    at least one enforcer agent to enforce the identified policies.

There were also Internet drafts published about this time and soon after that mentioned using RDF in a network management control layer: see https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-atarashi-netconfmodel-architecture-00 and https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-atarashi-xmlconf-architecture-00.

Answer (score 3):

This might have been anticipated by https://www.google.com/patents/US8464312 "Integrated network policy enforcement" :

> "**ABSTRACT** A method and system for integrating network policy
>   enforcement into an existing network infrastructure comprises a
>   communications bus that links expert policy devices, such as intrusion
>   prevention devices, with one or more connection points. The connection
>   points are network devices that are equipped with enforcement logic
>   for receiving reports of events via a published interface on the
>   communications bus about the existing network infrastructure from
>   either the policy devices or the connection points themselves, and
>   enforcing policy at the connection points by generating an action in
>   response to the reported events, including actions to block traffic,
>   remediate devices, limit bandwidth, and the like, until the reported
>   event has been addressed in a manner that ensures the security of the
>   existing network infrastructure."

and https://www.google.com/patents/WO2006070054A1 "Method and system for policy enforcement in a communication system" :

> "**ABSTRACT** The present invention discloses a method for smart buffering
>   for a policy resolution and policy enforcement system. The invention
>   can be applied to a communication system with one or several available
>   communication network(s). The trigger events and policy actions form
>   input and output buffers to be processed in the invention. Causal
>   relationships between the trigger events and policy actions are
>   stored. Priorities can be set to the trigger events and policy
>   actions. Sorting is made according to priorities. The buffer data can
>   be scheduled, in other words delayed, in order to rationalize the
>   policy management. The buffer data is combined if several trigger
>   events affect the same target or quantity. The buffer data is filtered
>   in the last step in order to simplify chained trigger events. The
>   trigger events of filtered input buffer are sent to the policy
>   resolution mechanism and the policy actions of filtered output buffer
>   are sent to the policy action enforcement."

Comment: Thanks for the answer pageman, but I think Semantic Web standards should be in the public domain.  Imagine if CERN didn't make the web free, we'd still be in Compuserve/Prodigy/Minitel/AOL land.